# Phonegap build - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

**THE APP**

I'm trying to create a simple app which takes a picture, am testing phonegap build

When the app loads I get a console log saying `deviceready` - which is logged when the device is ready

**THE PROBLEM**

When I click the button to fire the camera, I get a console error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined`

**JS / HTML**

```
<button onclick="app.takePicture();">Take Picture</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script>
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id); // <-- this works ok
    },

    takePicture: function() {
      navigator.camera.getPicture( function( imageURI ) {
        alert( imageURI );
      },
      function( message ) {
        alert( message );
      },
      {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
      });
    }
};

app.initialize();
</script>
```

I also tried with `cordova.js` but same issue exactly.

I've seen this issue mentioned before but cannot find a fix for it, is there one? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are all of the appropriate permissions and features in place? Check the answers on [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/18690388)

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out although can't find this documented anywhere!

Make sure you add this to your `config.xml` file:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" spec="0.3.6" source="pgb" />
```

This basically, from what I can gather, creates the `navigator` object